# Perfect Money API integration error

Tags: php, jquery, api

I am integrating Perfect Money on a project for Instant Payments. I am facing the errors here. I am applying all the information correctly but still its returning that the username and password supplied is incorrect. Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['req_pay']))
{
$f=fopen('https://perfectmoney.is/acct/confirm.asp?AccountID=myaccount&PassPhrase=mypassword&Payer_Account=U10428073&Payee_Account=U1234567&Amount=1&PAY_IN=1&PAYMENT_ID=1223', 'rb');

        if($f===false){
           echo 'error openning url';
        }

        // getting data
        $out=array(); $out="";
        while(!feof($f)) $out.=fgets($f);

        fclose($f);

        // searching for hidden fields
        if(!preg_match_all("/<input name='(.*)' type='hidden' value='(.*)'>/", $out, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
           echo 'Ivalid output';
           exit;
        }

        $ar="";
        foreach($result as $item){
           $key=$item[1];
           $ar[$key]=$item[2];
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($ar);
        echo '</pre>';

} 

?>
```

Comment: Replace `&` with  `%26`, the php-function is (surprise!) `urlencode`.

Comment: https://perfectmoney.is/acct/confirm.asp?AccountID=myaccount%26PassPhrase=mypassowrd 

try putting that URL with your own credentials on a new tab.. see can you login? I still cannot login.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally build an url using `http_build_query`, in your case something like

```
 $params = array('AccountID' => 'myaccount',
                 'PassPhrase' => 'mypassword',
                 'Payer_Account' => 'U10428073',
                 'Payee_Account' => 'U1234567',
                 'Amount' => 1,
                 'PAY_IN' => 1,
                 'PAYMENT_ID' => 1223,
           );
 $query = http_build_query($params);
 $url = 'https://perfectmoney.is/acct/confirm.asp?' . $query;
```

then open this url:

```
 $f = fopen($url);
```

Comment: edit my full code according to your own variables you have taken.

Comment: Please think for yourself -- if my assumptions are correct, I gave you all you need to fix your code yourself -- if I'm wrong you should find out soon enough.

Comment: Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\ptc\pm.php on line 114 

this is what I am getting now.. I replaced your $url with $f as in my code the URL was previously taken under the variable $f. What mistake am I making?

Comment: No - `$f = fopen($url);`

Comment: still not working.,. one more thing. That warning is being generated unlimited number of times thus hanging my browser firefox.

Comment: Try to use `$out = explode("\n",file_get_contents($url));` instead of your whole reading-code as a test; I assume the fopen() fails, but the error goes unnoticed in the following noise...